# I want to write a snowsql IFF statement with three or more criteria, but keep having an error

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Select *,  IFF((TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='XX6041','L-6041', 
IFF(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)='XX6042','L-6042', TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS) AS newform
From TARGET_QUIKPLAN;
```

Gives:

```
Error: SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 58 not enough arguments 
for function [IFF(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)], expected 3, got 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the issue is about the brackets. This one should work:

```
Select *, IFF(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS='XX6041','L-6041', IFF(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS='XX6042','L-6042', TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS)) AS newform From TARGET_QUIKPLAN;
```

Comment: Great! Please do not forget to mark the answer as correct! Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

In case when you need to nest `IFF` but still use the same condition between expression the much cleaner way is to use [DECODE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/decode.html) function:

> Compares the select expression to each search expression in order. As soon as a search expression matches the selection expression, the corresponding result expression is returned.
>
> ```
> DECODE( <expr> , <search1> , <result1> [ , <search2> , <result2> ... ] [ , <default> ] )
> ```

```
SELECT *, 
 DECODE(TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS, 'XX6041', 'L-6041',
                               'XX6042', 'L-6042',
                               TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS) AS newform
FROM TARGET_QUIKPLAN;
```

or `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS WHEN 'XX6041' THEN 'L-6041'
                               WHEN 'XX6042' THEN 'L-6042'
          ELSE TARGET_QUIKPLAN.FORMS END AS new
FROM TARGET_QUIKPLAN;
```